# How to check the presence on the channel on the server? (Laravel Echo, Socket.IO)

Tags: laravel, socket.io, laravel-echo

I need to see the online status/presence on the chat channel when I made initial request to the server without broadcasting authorization. How can I determine on the server if anyone is online?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/broadcasting#broadcasting-to-presence-channels

Answer (score 0):

**Found a solution** [**laravel-echo-serve http-api**](https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server#http-api)